# How to limit traffic on a router based on IP?

Tags: router, traffic-shaping

how to limit internet traffic on a router based on a LAN IP.
so that for example on a 10mb/s internet connection I can have a IP Camera with a dedicated 1mb/s, 2 computers with 3mb/s, and 2 computers with 6mb/s.

as far as I know it's called something like traffic-shaping...

I'm really not sure how this all is called, so please show me or point me at some guide for dummies. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is up to your router model. Not all allow this.  If you have a good enterprise-level router you'll find a way to do this. Usually cheap routers don't come with this capacity.

Get a Cisco or a high-level lynksys.

Or you can setup a computer as domain server and control all quotas from there.

Answer (score 1):

Most custom firmware such as dd-wrt, tomato etc. either support this out-of-the-box or have a version with particular QOS function support.

If you do not have the money to buy advanced routers, these firmware fits onto many available over the counter wireless routers and provide capabilities that exist in models costing thousands of dollars.

http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index -- dd-wrt
... http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/What_is_DD-WRT%3F different versions

http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato -- tomato firmware
... http://www.decimation.com/markw/2007/10/03/tomato-qos-setup/ tomato qos setups

good luck!